# Set module frontname programatically

Tags: module, configuration, url, url-rewrite, routing

In my magento admin area, admin can set a name to be displayed on the contact us page. For example, admin can set "contact-us" as the url-alias and I want to set that as the frontname of my contacts module. How to do that programatically?

Answer (score -1):

You don't necessarily have to do that programmatically, you can do it from the backend.

### Magento 1

Go to **Catalog > Url Rewrites.**

### Magento 2

Go to **Marketing > URL Rewrites.**

### Step by step

Click the Add URL Rewrite button.

Choose Custom in the drop down.

ID Path: contact-us

Request Path: contact-us

Target Path: contacts

Finally click the Save button.